# Anyone know good documentation on competitive banner rotation?

Tags: ads, banner

I am looking to code me a banner management system that has users make their own banners in a CPI system. Anyone have any recommendations or documentations to have their banners cycle? Or better yet, cycle competitively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into the concept of weighted randomization as this will help with what you are embarking on.

[Random weighted choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692/random-weighted-choice)

Of course this only addresses how things show against one another but it will insure that all the ads are shown appropriately for what is paid for.  Make sure that you system supports gif, jpeg, and flash and the bare minimum.  You will need to implement click tracking as well.  I also suggest looking into creating page specific locations not just site wide positions (such a site wide banner ad).  This will allow you to sell specific page oriented areas for things that are more specific to your sites content.  You may not need this initially but don't forget to add it to your initial design as you will need it down the road and it will help you track where you are getting the most impressions.