# Why use bitwise operations for sampling random without replacement in c#?

Tags: c#, random

Example [Select x random elements from a weighted list in C# (without replacement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775946/select-x-random-elements-from-a-weighted-list-in-c-sharp-without-replacement/42171066#42171066)

In this example of random sampling without replacement in c# why did the OP choose to use bitwise operations in the algorithm which counts the total weights and then selects which element is then to be chosen.

I searched the web for other examples of this algorithm but could not find any. Is it more efficient as it seems less readable from my perspective.

thanks.

Comment: [Heap (data structure)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))

Comment: The only bitwise operations I see in the linked question is doing `i << 1` or `i >> 1`, which is the same as multiplying or dividing by 2. It doesn't seem like it's related to the algorithm in general, but more like a syntactic shortcut to doing those two mathematical operations.