# How to write a random number generator with a weight in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, random

I am trying to write a random number generator function in C# that would take a **minimum**, **maximum**, and **weight** parameters.

With weight == 0, the result would equal minimum, and with weight == 1, the result would equal maximum. With weight == 0.5, all the numbers within the range would have equal chance of being selected.

What I want to achieve is as the weight is approaching the minimum, the minimum has more chances of being selected and the maximum less, and vice versa.

Comment: @Plutonix There are different distributions to regard. You seem to only consider the uniform distribution.

Comment: There are different ways to approach it. Could you give a few more examples on how the function is supposed to behave for weights like 0.1, 0.25, 0.66 etc.?

Comment: I'm having trouble deciding what exact values the other weights produce. For instance, if the weight were 0.1, the probability for minimum would be 90%, the maximum 10%, and the values in between would be assigned accordingly. However, I am not sure if the sum of all probabilities should be more than a 100%, as it would be in that case.

Comment: @tau-badger SO is more about specific coding problems, other stackexchange sites may help more..... Maybe http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question is far too broad. You have not provided any information as to what you've already tried, never mind a good [mcve] that shows this, nor any sort of precise specification that explains the type of random numbers you want to return nor _exactly_ how the weight will affect the distribution of the output. There are already a number of Q&A on Stack Overflow showing how to do weighted random selected (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692/random-weighted-choice); maybe those will address your question, or maybe they won't. There are too many ways to interpret this question.

Comment: @tau-badger I'm afraid that is a specification that you will need to provide. Otherwise, there are infinitely many ways to design the method. Statistically speaking, the sum of all the possible outcomes' probabilities **must** be 100%. Are min/max the only values to be produced or do you need **any** number between min and max to be possible?

Comment: I see now I've posted the question without a solid enough grasp of the problem itself, but some of the answers here are pointing me in the right direction. @KonradViltersten I need any number between the extremes, including the extremes.

Comment: @tau-badger In such case, you are looking for a *continuous distribution function* and hance, the probability of the max/min can not be 10% and 90%. It is kind of a math stat issue on university level, so I am glad that you are realizing the graspiness needed. :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten Oh. That is problematic as I evidently don't have a solid enough math background to even understand the difficulty involved with such problems. Thank you, Konrad. You saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 15):

I have a short tutorial describing how to do that here:

https://ericlippert.com/2012/02/21/generating-random-non-uniform-data/

Summary:

- State the function parameterized by your weighting parameter that gives the *probability distribution* function.
- Use calculus to integrate that function to get the *cumulative distribution function*.
- Invert that function to get the *quantile function*.
- Implement the quantile function, and pass the output of a uniformly distributed random source into the quantile function. The result will be a random source that conforms to the desired distribution.
- Transform that function onto your integer range, and round appropriately.

Comment: It will take me a while to implement this, but from a cursory look, it seems to be what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is one from infinite number of possibilities to get weighted values from `[0, 1]`:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
double weight = ...; // must be in [0, 1];

double r = rnd.NextDouble();
if (weight < 0.5)
    val = 1 - Math.Pow(r, weight * 2);
else
    val = Math.Pow(r, (1 - weight) * 2);
```

It can be mapped to `[min, max]` as

```
double val2 = val * (max - min) + min;
```

Comment: this is wrong, your weight affects not only probability but amplitude as well

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Oops, thanks! Hopefully corrected :).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is use the [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), finding functions of your weight which lead to the desired behavior.

For example, assume that the support is between 0 and 1, and that the weight $w$ is also between 0 and 1. The Beta has two parameters, $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Let $\alpha=2*w$ and $\beta=-wlog_2(w)-(1-w)*log_2(1-2)$ (which happens to be the [binary entropy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function). Then the Beta is degenerate for weights 0 and 1, a standard uniform for a weight of 0.5, and gives valid continuous distributions for other weight values. This particular re-parametrization of the Beta may not be exactly what you want but you could play around with similar functions.