# Weighting a List to make items with a lower index having a higher chance of being randomly chosen?

Tags: c#, random

I am receiving a `List<Fruit>` of unkown size, usually between 4-10 items:

```
{ Apples, Orange, Pear, ?, ?, ... }
```

How can I weight the `List` in a way that `Apples` have the highest % chance of being selected, then `Orange`, then `Pear`?

The effect should essentially be the same as picking a random item from a `List` that looks like this:

```
{ Apples, Apples, Apples, Apples, Orange, Orange, Pear }
```

If the `List` was of a fixed size, I would've done

1. Generate a float between 0.0-1.0;
2. If `< 0.4`, return `Apples`. Else if `< 0.75` return `Orange` etc.

Note that this question is not about [selecting a random item from a weighted list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692/random-weighted-choice) but about weighting an existing `List` of arbitrary length in a way that a random pick will result in an Item's probability of being picked proportional to its position in the `List`.

Comment: Have you tried implementing the "effect" that you mention at the end?

Comment: You have the right idea. Just create a *weighting function" that you can use to adjust the weights any way you want

Comment: This is a very useful question, but your title was going to lower its searchability (and therefore, future usefulness) substantially.

Comment: Hi Nathan I haven't tried implementing the {Apple, Apple, Orange} method because I have 15 types of fruits and it'll probably hard to read - to interpret what % chance each item has - and tweaking the % when the List becomes longer

Comment: Not a duplicate - the other question is concerned with selecting a random element from a *pre-weighted* set, this one is concerned with *weighting* a set.

Comment: @vzwick please edit question to reflect that (don't forget to edit in link to the current duplicate) and ping me to re-open. Also make sure it matches your answer (i.e. "weights must be going as powers of two" or something like that)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Good suggestions. Ping ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var weightedItems = myList
    .Select((item, index)
        => new { Item = item, Weight = 1f / Math.Pow(2, index) });
```

This will give you an `IEnumerable` of tuples of the `Item` and a `Weight` that gets smaller as the `Item`'s `index` increases. I.e:

```
Item = Apples, Weight = 1
Item = Orange, Weight = 0.5
Item = Pear  , Weight = 0.25
```

etc.

You can obviously tune the `1f / Math.Pow(2, index)` part (which calculates the weight) to your liking. The one I used has the nice-ish side effect of yielding `1 >= n > 0` which is a predictable range and making each item half as likely to get picked as the previous one.

Selecting a random item from this structure according to your requirement could be done like this:

- Generate a random number between 1 and 0
- Iterate the IEnumerable from lowest to highest `Weight`
- Return the first item where `Weight >= your random number`

Comment: @SirMt I actually fudged up the weighting function on my first try - `1 / (index + 1)` makes the "choose the first element larger or equal to a random number between 0 and 1" approach more likely to return the 3rd element than the 2nd. The `Math.Pow` takes care of that.

Comment: Both methods are fantastic starting points to tweak towards the behavior I wanted. Very helpful